# SLD PropertyIsNotEqualTo

Tags: sld

I would like to draw a symbol if the attribute LIGHTING is not ('N' or 'NO' or 'Unknown').
I can see why the below doesn't work, How do I specify 'AND' in the SLD-filter?

```
<ogc:PropertyIsNotEqualTo>
    <ogc:PropertyName>LIGHTING</ogc:PropertyName>
    <ogc:Literal>N</ogc:Literal>
    <ogc:Literal>NO</ogc:Literal>
    <ogc:Literal>Unknown</ogc:Literal>
 </ogc:PropertyIsNotEqualTo>
```

Comment: <ogc:Or> is your friend

Answer (score 1):

You need to chain ogc:And together, e.g.:

```
<ogc:And>
    <ogc:PropertyIsNotEqualTo>
        <ogc:PropertyName>LIGHTING</ogc:PropertyName>
        <ogc:Literal>N</ogc:Literal>
    </ogc:PropertyIsNotEqualTo>
    <ogc:And>
        <ogc:PropertyIsNotEqualTo>
            <ogc:PropertyName>LIGHTING</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>No</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:PropertyIsNotEqualTo>
        <ogc:PropertyIsNotEqualTo>
            <ogc:PropertyName>LIGHTING</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>Unknown</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:PropertyIsNotEqualTo>
    </ogc:And>
</ogc:And>
```

https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/reference/filters.html#logical-operators